# ¿Como hacer un insert y un update al mismo tiempo (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla **registrohora**, que la secuencia sql es la siguiente:

```
$sql = "insert into registrohora values ('', '$rut', '$rutm', '$hoact', '$fecsec', '1', '$feact', '$horate')";

'' = id del registro
'$rut' = el rut o identificación del paciente
'$rutm' = el rut o identificación del medico
'$hoact' = hora actual
'$fecsec' = fecha seleccionada
'1' = el estado del registro (1 significa 'en aprobación')
'$feact' = fecha actual
'$horate' = hora de atención
```

Respecto a lo ultimo, las horas de atención van dentro de una tabla llama **horario** (id, atencion y disponibilidad), la columna estado va conectada a otra tabla llamada **disponible** (id y tipo_dis) y dentro de ella esta 1 (disponible) y 2 (ocupado)

A lo que vengo es que aparte de hacer un **insert**, lo que quiero hacer también es un **update**, que cuando selecciono una hora (ejemplo: 8:00 - 9:00 o 10:00 - 10:30) de la tabla horario y cuando ingrese la hora a la tabla **registrohora** la **disponibilidad** (horario) de la hora que se seleccionó se cambie a 2 (o sea ocupada).

Por si acaso dejo adjunto como es mi base de datos del consultorio medico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no haces un `Trigger`? Un trigger es una parte del código que se ejecuta automáticamente como reacción de una operación especifica (INSERT, UPDATE O DELETE) sobre dicha tabla

Comment: Necesitas un disparador de base de datos o `trigger` en tabla `registrohora`. Ahora si entendí bien, el `update` se tiene que efectuar en el campo `estado` de la misma tabla `registrohora`? Si es así el tipo de `trigger` que necesitas es `before insert`

Comment: Otro consejo, no armes a mano el SQL, si se te complica usar un framework, usa PDO al menos

Comment: @JuanRom no es en estado, lo que quiero hacer es que se cambie **disponibilidad** de la tabla **horario**, de 1 a 2 cuando se haya seleccionado una de las horas que estan en la tabla horario e ingresado el registro a la tabla **registrohora**

Comment: ok, entonces podes usar un `trigger` `after insert` en tabla `registrohora` cuya instrucción será la de `actualizar` campo `disponibilidad` de tabla `horario`. Ahora paso respuesta

Comment: por ahora te lo debo por que para publicar la respuesta tengo que asegurarme que funcione bien y para ello debo crear algunas tablas, y hoy imposible.. Pero  probá hacerlo, busca info para crear ese trigger que mencioné